# final static object in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Is there a difference? What is the preferred or correct usage in groovy. If my variable is final and static should I be using def ?

```
final static def MY_STRING
```

or

```
final static String MY_STRING
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no one variation that's better in all circumstances.  By specifying the type with `String`, you can get compile-time type checking by using the [`@TypeChecked`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/TypeChecked.html) or [`@CompileStatic`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html) annotations.  If you don't specify a type, you can leave off `def` entirely, for slightly more concise code:

```
final static MY_STRING
```

Choose the one that matches your own priorities and coding style.

Comment: You can leave the type out and use `@TypeChecked` for type inference: `@TypeChecked class Foo { final static BAR = 'bar' }`, i believe